# Scriptural reference to explain what the word "gospel" means?

Tags: gospel

Would someone explain what the word gospel means and give a biblical reference which contains the word?

Comment: Did you look it up on Wikipedia? Your question is answered there: [Gospel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel). This site is for questions whose answers can't be easily found just by looking them up in standard references. For more on what this site is all about, please see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites). For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the Greek word *euangelizō* is "good news." (*Koiné* Greek is the original language of the New Testament.) A familiar verse with *euangelizō* in it is Luke 2:10, which reads,

> But the angel said [to the shepherds], "Do not be afraid; for behold, I bring you **good news** [i.e., *euangelizō*] of great joy which will be for all the people; for today in the city of David there has been born for you a Savior, who is Christ the Lord" (including v.11).

Interestingly, an *evangelist*, a person who is empowered by the Holy Spirit of God and then given to the church, is one who is gifted to spread the glad tidings that Jesus is both Savior and Lord (see Ephesians 4:11-12).

Evangelists are like obstetricians (so-called "baby doctors") who are gifted by God to help bring spiritual newborns into the kingdom of Jesus Christ and his universal church. When evangelists preach the good news, people get saved by believing on and receiving Jesus into their lives as their rescuer and boss.

I encourage you to use a concordance to look up the word *news*, which appears numerous times in the New Testament (at least 43 times in the New International Version of the Bible) in order to get a well-rounded view of what the gospel of Jesus Christ is.

Comment: εὐαγγελίζω is a **verb**; strictly speaking, it doesn't mean "good news", then. The noun is εὐαγγέλιον, and it doesn't appear in Luke, but. cf. Matthew 4:23; 9:35. It is frequent in Paul, though: Romans 1:16 is probably the occurence with the clearest implied definition. It is not so hard, these days, to follow up the terms in Greek via translation: e.g. [verb](http://goo.gl/ou99Iq), or [noun](http://goo.gl/eUw5ug).

Comment: @David: Thank you for the additional information. Feel free to edit my answer. Thanks, too, for the hyperlink. It introduced me to a pretty neat tool! It's kind of like an interlinear NT but with a few modifications and additions (je.g., Strong's numbering system). By the way, I was using the Goodrich & Kohlenberger NIV Exhaustive Concordance for my feeble attempt to 'splain "good news" to the OP. Don